# Adding a dependency existing internally as a dependency

Tags: maven, maven-3

My project is a fairly large project consisting of many maven modules (but not microservices). I was trying to do [Moving from spring to spring-bom on WAS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41105500/moving-from-spring-to-spring-bom-on-was) but seems lot of clashes in versions. So for example one of my modules is using `commons-collections`version 2.6.0 and my current project is using 3.2.2. I want the same jar to be used across. Since its more of a migration project I cannot do changes in container or repository changes at this time. I should only make sure that all the version are compatible with each other. My plan :

> I want to include a dependency which is with in some other dependency
>   into the current pom as a dependency.

Also I want other jars in this pom (which exists as a dependency) to included the dependency 
Is there anyway to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't completely understand your question, but the  can help you to define a cross-module dependency version, as long as you place it in the parent-pom file.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

and then define the dependency in the relevant module without providing it a version (it will be inherited from the parent-pom's `<dependencyManagment>` tag:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>project-1</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: I know, this is not what I am expecting. I am talking about a case where the dependency is not a child module. Its a separate one so my current module uses say `logger-1.9.0.SNAPSHOT.jar` and some other module which will be added as a dependency has `logger-1.7.0.SNAPSHOT.jar` and to prevent issues want to have same version say 1.9.0 across my platform. It would also be fine if you could let me know how to stop this transitive dependency also so that whatever is there in a module is not used or creates conflicts with other modules.

Comment: @Raghuveer transitive dependencies can be restriceted using `<exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>` for example

Comment: @nullpointer yes there are many of them so the best way is to explicitly tell the current service to use a particular version of a dependency from a dependency. So any help on that ?